# stochastic process: multiply two poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider the process $\{X(t),t\ge0\}$ defined by
$$X(t)=N(t)-\lambda t$$
where $N$ is a Poisson process with rate $\lambda \gt 0$
I have multiple questions about this one:

1. Compute, for $t_1, t_2, n_1, n_2 \gt 0$, the second-order probability mass of $N, G(t_1,t_2;n_1,n_2)$.
2. Compute $\mathbb E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]$, for $0 \lt t_1 \le t_2$.

For the problem 2, I don't know if there is correlation between $N(t_1)\cdot N(t_2)$ to compute its expectation.

Comment: Your question is phrased in language suitable for assigning homework. That tends to be frowned on here.

Answer (score 0):

The Poisson process has a kind of Markov property: the distribution of $N(s_2) - N(s_1)$, and hence the distribution of $X(s_2) - X(s_1)$, depends only on the length of the interval and is in particular independent of $N(s_1)$ or $X(s_1)$. (This property comes from the definition of the Poisson process.)

To exploit that here, use the identity $X(t_1) X(t_2) = X(t_1) \left[( X(t_2) - X(t_1)) + X(t_1)\right].$

Comment: Thank you! So actually $\mathbb E[X(t_1)X(t_2)]=\mathbb E[X(t_1)]\mathbb E[X(t_2)-X(t_1)]+\mathbb E[(X(t_1)^2]$ and since $\mathbb E[X(t_1)]=0$,  it equals to $\mathbb E[(X(t_1)^2]=\lambda t_1$ Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed, and you can go further; one of the terms you've written is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! Is the $Var[X(t_1)]=Var[N(t_1)]=\lambda t_1$?

Answer (score 0):

No way I'm doing parts (1)-(5) of a problem, but you did ask one actual question about the problem so I'll give a hint for that. We can write $$ N(t_1)N(t_2) = N(t_1)^2 + N(t_1)(N(t_2)-N(t_1)) = N(t_1)^2 + (N(t_1)-N(0))(N(t_2)-N(t_1))$$ and you know (from the definition of a Poisson process) a great deal about the joint distribution of the factors in the second term.

Comment: Thank you so much! but actually I have get the answer to be $\lambda t_1$ It's a bit strange to me.

Comment: can you also give a hint of how to prove it is a martingale?

Comment: @Qing Why is that strange? (It's right). Use (again) the fact that by independent increments $N(t_2)-N(t_1)$ is independent of $N(t_1) = N(t_1)-N(0).$ (You'll be using this fact a lot).

Comment: Thank you so much, below is my approach to prove the martingale, but I don't know if it is right: A process is said to be a martingale if only satisfies three conditions, the first two are easy to prove, I'm more focused on the third one: $\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]=X_s $for all $s \lt t$

Comment: $\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]=X_s $for all $s \lt t$ $$\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[N(t)-\lambda  t|\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[(N(t)-\lambda  t)-(N(s)-\lambda  s)+(N(s)-\lambda  s)||\mathcal F_s]=\mathbb E[(N(t)-N(S)-\lambda  (t-s)|\mathcal F_s]+\mathbb E[X_s|\mathcal F_s]=X(s)$$

Comment: @Qing I think the crux of the whole thing is showing that $E[N_t-N_s - \lambda(t-s)\mid \mathcal F_s] = 0$ (since $E(X_s\mid F_s) = X_s$ by the (unstated) definition of $\mathcal F_s$.) You weren't very explicit about why that part was true, although it follows more-or-less from my hint.